# Using unittest library App Shut down issue

Tags: python, unit-testing, appium

I am using python unnitest to test my app.

There are two methods in one class.

After first method is finished. App shut down(maybe tearDown)
After that app restart and secoun method is called.

```
class MainTest(unittest.TestCase):  
    @classmethod   
    def setUp(cls):    desired_cap = {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appium:decviceName": "xxx",
    "appium:appPackage": "appPackage",
    "appium:appActivity": "appActivity"    }    capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_cap)    cls.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',options=capabilities_options) def test_case_Popup(self):
      self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH,value='//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.lotte:id/btnAgree"]').click()   time.sleep(3)
      self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH,value='//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.lotte:id/btnDisAgree"]').click()
     
      time.sleep(3)   def test_case_MainBanner(self):
      self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH,value='//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.lotte:id/btnAgree"]').click()
      time.sleep(3)
      self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH,value='//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.lotte:id/btnDisAgree"]').click()
      
      time.sleep(3)
      image_element = self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH,value='//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id="com.lotte:id/bannerImage"]')
      image_size= image_element.size
      self.assertTrue(image_size['width'] > 0 and image_size['height'] > 0, "Error.")   # @classmethod
     def tearDown(cls):
     cls.driver.quit() if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MainTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

I don't want my app restarted untill whole methods are finished